# FPC module breaks sites - what are the alternatives?

Tags: module, full-page-cache

Today I installed the [Lesti FPC module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc.html). In our test environment this worked great and speeded up things a lot. So I installed it on production. The effect was much less significant. In the end I had to disable the module because it turned out it break several sites.

We tried to install APC, but this turned out to break our Magento installation. We needed to install several PHP libraries (if I recall correctly php-pear, php-devel, pecl, php-apc), and somehow this broke our Magento installation. To be sure we reverted to a snapshot.

Now I'm wondering what alternatives I have. I turned on compiling.

- Should I try a paid module like [Full Page Cache Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/full-page-cache-pro.html)?
- Do I have to remove the Lesti module?

Comment: Have you tried Varnish?

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both

Comment: I've updated the question. I've looked at Varnish, and it seems quite complex to configure. Do I need a module to handle this? At the moment I'm more interested in FPC Pro, with its support and money back guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at our caching solution [Evolved Caching](http://store.husseycoding.co.uk/evolved-caching).  Although Lesti_FPC cache is free, due to the way it (and in fact many other paid solutions) serves cached content the performance is - in the developers own words "not that good".  Have a look at [this page](http://gordonlesti.com/building-lesti_fpc2/) where the developer discusses his efforts to create Lesti_FPC2 - at the moment unsuccessfully.

We believe that Evolved Caching really is a long way ahead of other caching solutions (free or paid, or indeed EE FPC) both in terms of both performance, and the range of caching scenarios and store setups it caters for.  In terms of performance, it is comparable to Varnish easily achieving sub 100ms full page HTML generation times (on our very modestly specced store we consistently get 40ms).

Setting up Varnish for a good hit rate on a Magento store is time consuming and difficult but Evolved Caching also integrates directly with Varnish to give a cache hit on every page you visit, regardless of login status or cart contents (unless you have excluded the page from caching in the extension admin settings).  Setup is extremely easy, you just need to use [our .vcl configuration file](http://husseycoding.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/evolved-caching-and-varnish.html) on a completely default Varnish install.  Worth noting also that all hole punching is all done in admin, you don't need to touch any code.

Basically Evolved Caching was developed to be an extremely high performing, very user friendly caching solution which addresses all of the shortcomings found in competing products.  If you want to have a look at the extension guide then you can do [here](http://husseycoding.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/evolved-caching-magento-extension_18.html).

We also offer a completely unrestricted, free 30 day trial of the extension, just fill in the form [here](http://store.husseycoding.co.uk/trial), and after purchase we offer a no questions asked money back guarantee.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this on a test domain in a similar environment, without varnish. That makes it possible to compare directly.

Comment: Great, just sent out the extension and trial license.