# What tests perform after moving Magento to another host?

Tags: hosting

I have asked to move a website on Magento to another hosting provider. The technical assistance of the hosting provider did this operation.

I have made some tests on public side and in the admin panel. Things seems working apart two timeouts.

What kind of tests would you perform at this point to watch if the site is working properly in all its functionalities?

Are there some tools to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is where a set of functional tests would come in handy. But, since you didn't mention one, here's what I'd do:

- Create an order, from the backend and the front end. Ordering is core eCommerce functionality - without that working properly, your stores not gonna do much.
- check your site emails. Ensure that they're sending properly and there aren't any broken images.
- try to create an account. Try to login, and log out.

Those are the top things I would test. I'm not aware of a tool that would test this for you.

Comment: I made a valid order from the front end. What do you mean with an order from the backend?

Comment: I'm doing all of these tests. Apart an order from the backend. After those will you try some performance tests about website speed, loading of the pages or what?

Comment: An order from the backend is a order created in the admin panel.

Comment: Yes, those are some good ones that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Do you know some specific tools for Magento to do those tests?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used any, but this might be helpful: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/benchmarking-magento-performance-between-2-servers. Thanks for accepting!