# How to change the memory limit for php

Tags: php

The problem I am having is that my site is slow after you import my products with magmi

http://fpm5.5-check.cluster015.ovh.net/phpinfo.php

After searching the memory of my php of origin here is what I find the memory_limit is has 512 but why the homepage of my site is also slow?

Comment: memory_limit being exceeded causes crashes, not slowness.

Comment: Not directly related but optimization advice: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both/13992#13992

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `memory_limit` setting should have no effect on Magento's performance. It only sets the high threshold of memory usage by PHP processes, and if Magento hogs more memory than that limit, you will get errors, but it changing it won't make things faster.

I would strongly advice against modifying `memory_limit` to anything other than the recommended value unless you know what you're doing. Setting it too low may cause some of your Magento pages to crash, and setting it too high might cause your entire server to slow down to a halt in extreme cases.

Instead, I would advise searching the Web on some tips on how to optimize Magento's performance. There are many relevant posts that can point you in the right direction. [This post](http://www.shoppimon.com/content/2015/01/optimizing-magento-performance-solutions-help-speed-shop/) on my company's blog is one example, but there are many others. Enabling various forms of caching, using a CDN and optimizing your DB settings are probably the first places you want to look into.

BTW, I would also strongly advise against posting your server's phpinfo() output publicly for security reasons. You should remember to delete that file as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the memory limit globally in php.ini, look for this line:

***memory_limit =***

and adjust the value acording to your needs, also you can do it in line in any given file you want like this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1G");
```

Comment: In what file I have to change cela? In my .htacces Magento or server?

Comment: php.ini is located in your server, the path to your file depends on the server, normal places are: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, etc. If you can't modify your php.ini then just use ini_set instead, add that line after the <?php to any file, for instance index.php. This should a temporary solution for testing, is always better to do this on the php.ini

Comment: How to access to this kind of file?

Comment: If you don't know then is very unlikely that I can help you. Ask to your hosting company for access or to change the memory_limit themselves

Comment: OK I would ask Monday.

Comment: But you really think that's what slowed the homepage of my magento after an import bulk with magmi?

Comment: I couldn't say with so little information.

Comment: I will explain I import my product with magmi. After you import my products I am doing a reindex with magento and it is at this time that my site has become slow my home page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24785/discussion-between-lloiacono-and-webevolution).

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: Just follow the link in my previous comment and we can chat here

Comment: You should really not set `memory_limit` too high, see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You will try with magento cache extensions. There are lot of magento extension available in Magento connect.

In magento, by default its has cache managment in admin. I hope you enable the cache in magento admin.

Please refer this link below, it will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403184/what-are-the-best-steps-to-improve-magento-performance