# My site is taking a Full minute to load due to slow queries?

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento Site , using a Theme, is taking a Full Minute to load up !!

The Host Provider has advise its due to SLO"W QUERIES.
I'm using a 4GB RAM Server, so dont think it's the problem.

Optimising the Tables has not resolved the problem.

Does anyone know if the the "Full Page Cache" Extensions will resolve the problem ?

Or is the Theme Template faulty ?

I really like the Theme since it's best suited to the business model & want to continue using it.

How can i resolve the issue of SLOW QUERIES ?

Pls help.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both/13992#13992

Answer (score 1):

To be able to see which queries are slow, you can edit the following file `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

And change the following variable to true:

```
protected $_debug               = true;
```

The slow queries will be logged under the `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` file.

You can change the query durations to be logged by changing the following variable:

```
protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05;
```

Comment: Thanks - but how can I resolve the issue of slow queries ? Deploy FPC Magento Extension or change the theme template ?

Comment: It depends on the queries you'll get in the logs. Your question is way too broad to be able to help you. You need to find where the issue comes from first.

Comment: Can I send you the slow query log to have a look at ?

Comment: Post it in your question

Comment: Here you go. http://sangyug-ke.com/mysql-slow.log.txt

Comment: Well there's a lot of queries in there, empty the log file and try changing the `$_logQueryTime` to 5.

Comment: Pls bear with me.  I' m working on it.

Comment: http://sangyug-ke.com/market/slow_queries.txt

Comment: The link above was just generated. Its  the top 10 slow queries of all 194

Comment: Well you found the issue. You have a module that deals with tables called starting with `isc_`.

Comment: Great.  What's next step ?

Comment: Well we can't help you more, it's a community module so it does not belong to magento stackexchange I suggest you contact the developer

Comment: Are you saying something wrong with the theme template ?  I should to another one ?

Comment: I dont know if it's related to the theme, it's related to a module that's all I know. If the module comes with the theme then yes it's theme related but right now I don't know

Comment: The log file shows  database sangyugk_aw2, which apparently does not belong to domain site that is slow on load-up.   So I asked this qtn to Siteground Support.  His response : Quote: "I have found that the sangyugk_aw2 named database is used by your application used by sangyug-ke.com domain name . i have found that in the following file:
Code:
/home/sangyugk/public_html/config/config.php"

Comment: The slow site in qtn is sub domain sangyug-ke.com/market.  I dont know why the slow query log file is showing db that does not belong to sub domain site ?

Comment: Ask a new answer as its a différent subject