# Catalog_product_index_price too big to reindex

Tags: magento-1.8, price, catalog

i have Catalog_product_index_price and Catalog_product_index_price_idx talbles which are 1G large with 10 million rows each. the catalog has ~ 500K products.

I'm trying to reindex the catalog_product_price but to no avail, the mysql server crashes every time even when i increased the timeout.

I know that the size of the tables are the reason why it's unable to complete. What options do i have to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you try it with command line.

Comment: Did you tried reindexing from Shell ? http://inchoo.net/magento/executing-magento-indexer-from-shell/  If it will cause same issue with database crash, I think you'll have only 2 options - improve mysql server performance OR reindex all products with custom script like this - https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AsyncIndex (not tested by us)

Comment: Yes, i did but to no avail.

Comment: I've had good fun with indexing. The improvements that EE provides for indexing are a big help with this as it allows you to do partial indexes. There's a free option for CE - https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AsyncIndex I've had no experience with it but it was one of the options suggested to me when I had something similar happening - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130103/redis-timeout-after-a-reindex