# Slow Queries crashing mysql server

Tags: magento-community, sql

I've tracked down a super large query that is built in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract::_getLoadAttributesSelect that is setting an obscene amount of ids in the IN() clause...

What is causing this?  (I couldn't even post the full query b/c it's too long.  It calls this same type query for catalog_category_entity_text, catalog_category_entity_int, catalog_category_entity_decimal, etc.

`# Query_time: 7.486893  Lock_time: 0.049128  Rows_sent: 85083  Rows_examined: 648775
SET timestamp=1497033909;
SELECT`t_d`.`entity_id`,`t_d`.`attribute_id`,`t_d`.`value`AS`default_value`,`t_s`.`value`AS`store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS`value`FROM`catalog_category_entity_text`AS`
t_d
 `LEFT JOIN`catalog_category_entity_text`AS`t_s`ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 3) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 5214,
 5215, 5216, 5217, 5218, 5219, 5220, 5221, 5222, 5223, 5224, 5225, 5226, 5227, 5228, 5229, 5230, 5231, 5232, 5233, 5234, 5235, 5236, 5237, 5238, 5239, 5240, 5241, 5242, 5243, 5244, 5245, 5246, 5247, 5248, 5249,
 5250, 5251, 5252, 5253, 5254, 5255, 5256, 5257, 5258, 5259, 5260, 5261, 5262, 5263, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5268, 5269, 5270, 5271, 5272, 5273, 5274, 5275, 5276, 5277, 5278, 5279, 5280, 5281, 5282, 5283, 5284,
 5285, 5286, 5287, 5288, 5289, 5290, 5291, 5292, 5293, 5294, 5295, 5296, 5297, 5298, 5299, 5300, 5301, 5302, 5303, 5304, 5305, 5306, 5307, 5308, 5309, 5310, 5311, 5312, 5313, 5314, 5315, 5316, 5317, 5318, 5319,
 5320, 5321, 5322, 5323, 5324, 5325, 5326, 5327, 5328, 5329, 5330, 5331, 5332, 5333, 5334, 5335, 5336, 5337, 5338, 5339, 5340, 5341, 5342, 5343, 5344, 5345, 5346, 5347, 5348, 5349, 5350, 5351, 5352, 5353, 5354,
 5355, 5356, 5357, 5358, 5359, 5360, 5361, 5362, 5363, 5364, 5365, 5366, 5367, 5368, 5369, 5370, 5371, 5372, 5373, 5374, 5375, 5376, 5377, 5378, 5379, 5380, 5381, 5382, 5383, 5384, 5385, 5386, 5387, 5388, 5389,
 5390, 5391, 5392, 5393, 5394, 5395, 5396, 5397, 5398, 5399, 5400, 5401, 5402, 5403, 5404, 5405, 5406, 5407, 5408, 5409, 5410, 5411, 5412, 5413, 5414, 5415, 5416, 5417, 5418, 5419, 5420, 5421, 5422, 5423, 5424,
 5425, 5426, 5427, 5428, 5429, 5430, 5431, 5432, 5433, 5434, 5435, 5436, 5437, 5438, 5439, 5440, 5441, 5442, 5443, 5444, 5445, 5446, 5447, 5448, 5449, 5450, 5451, 5452, 5453, 5454, 5455, 5456, 5457, 5458, 5459,
 5460, 5461, 5462, 5463, 5464, 5465, 5466, 5467, 5468, 5469, 5470, 5471, 5472, 5473, 5474, 5475, 5476, 5477, 5478, 5479, 5480, 5481, 5482, 5483, 5484, 5485, 5486, 5487, 5488, 5489, 5490, 5491, 5492, 5493, 5494,
 5495, 5496, 5497, 5498, 5499, 5500, 5501, 5502, 5503, 5504, 5505, 5506, 5507, 5508, 5509, 5510, 5511, 5512, 5513, 5514, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 5524, 5525, 5526, 5527, 5528, 5529,
 5530, 5531, 5532, 5533, 5534, 5535, 5536, 5537, 5538, 5539, 5540, 5541, 5542, 5543, 5544, 5545, 5546, 5547, 5548, 5549, 5550, 5551, 5552, 5553, 5554, 5555, 5556, 5557, 5558, 5559, 5560, 5561, 5562, 5563, 5564,
 5565, 5566, 5567, 5568, 5569, 5570, 5571, 5572, 5573, 5574, 5575, 5576, 5577, 5578, 5579, 5580, 5581, 5582, 5583, 5584, 5585, 5586, 5587, 5588, 5589, 5590, 5591, 5592, 5593, 5594, 5595, 5596, 5597, 5598, 5599,
 5600, 5601, 5602, 5603, 5604, 5605, 5606, 5607, 5608, 5609, 5610, 5611, 5612, 5613, 5614, 5615, 5616, 5617, 5618, 5619, 5620, 5621, 5622, 5623, 5624, 5625, 5626, 5627, 5628, 5629, 5630, 5631, 5632, 5633, 5634,
 5635, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5639, 5640, 5641, 5642, 5643, 5644, 5645, 5646, 5647, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5652, 5653, 5654, 5655, 5656, 5657, 5658, 5659, 5660, 5661, 5662, 5663, 5664, 5665, 5666, 5667, 5668, 5669,
 5670, 5671, 5672, 5673, 5674, 5675, 5676, 5677, 5678, 5679, 5680, 5681, 5682, 5683, 5684, 5685, 5686, 5687, 5688, 5689, 5690, 5691, 5692, 5693, 5694, 5695, 5696, 5697, 5698, 5699, 5700, 5701, 5702, 5703, 5704,
 5705, 5706, 5707, 5708, 5709, 5710, 5711, 5713, 5714, 5715, 5716, 5717, 5718, 5719, 5720, 5721, 5722, 5723, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5737, 5738, 5739, 5740,
 5741, 5742, 5743, 5744, 5745, 5746, 5747, 5748, 5749, 5750, 5751, 5752, 5753, 5754, 5755, 5756, 5757, 5758, 5759, 5760, 5761, 5762, 5763, 5764, 5765, 5766, 5767, 5768, 5769, 5770, 5771, 5772, 5773, 5774, 5775,
 5776, 5777, 5778, 5779, 5780, 5781, 5782, 5783, 5784, 5785, 5786, 5787, 5788, 5789, 5790, 5791, 5792, 5793, 5794, 5795, 5796, 5797, 5798, 5799, 5800, 5801, 5802, 5803, 5804, 5805, 5806, 5807, 5808, 5809, 5810,
 5811, 5812, 5813, 5814, 5815, 5816, 5817, 5818, 5819, 5820, 5821, 5822, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5826, 5827, 5828, 5829, 5830, 5831, 5832, 5833, 5834, 5835, 5836, 5837, 5838, 5839, 5840, 5841, 5842, 5843, 5844, 5845,
 5846, 5847, 5848, 5849, 5850, 5851, 5852, 5853, 5854, 5855, 5856, 5857, 5858, 5859, 5860, 5861, 5862, 5863, 5864, 5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5869, 5870, 5871, 5872, 5873, 5874, 5875, 5876, 5877, 5878, 5879, 5880,
 5881, 5882, 5883, 5884, 5885, 5886, 5887, 5888, 5889, 5890, 5891, 5892, 5893, 5894, 5895, 5896, 5897, 5898, 5899, 5900, 5901, 5902, 5903, 5904, 5905, 5906, 5907, 5908, 5909, 5910, 5911, 5912, 5913, 5914, 5915,
 5916, 5917, 5918, 5919, 5920, 5921, 5922, 5923, 5924, 5925, 5926, 5927, 5928, 5929, 5930, 5931, 5932, 5933, 5934, 5935, 5936, 5937, 5938, 5939, 5940, 5941, 5942, 5943, 5944, 5945, 5946, 5947, 5948, 5949, 5950,
 5951, 5952, 5953, 5954, 5955, 5956, 5957, 5958, 5959, 5960, 5961, 5962, 5963, 5964, 5965, 5966, 5967, 5968, 5969, 5970, 5971, 5972, 5973, 5974, 5975, 5976, 5977, 5978, 5979, 5980, 5981, 5982, 5983, 5984, 5985,
 5986, 5987, 5988, 5989, 5990, 5991, 5992, 5993, 5994, 5995, 5996, 5997, 5998, 5999, 6000, 6001, 6002, 6003, 6004, 6005, 6006, 6007, 6008, 6009, 6010, 6011, 6012, 6013, 6014, 6015, 6016, 6017, 6018, 6019, 6020,
 6021, 6022, 6023, 6024, 6025, 6026, 6027, 6028, 6029, 6030, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6034, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6039, 6040, 6041, 6042, 6043, 6044, 6045, 6046, 6047, 6048, 6049, 6050, 6051, 6052, 6053, 6054, 6055,
 6056, 6057, 6058, 6059, 6060, 6061, 6062, 6063, 6064, 6065, 6066, 6067, 6068, 6069, 6070, 6071, 6072, 6073, 6074, 6075, 6076, 6077, 6078, 6079, 6080, 6081, 6082, 6083, 6084, 6085, 6086, 6087, 6088, 6089, 6090,6091, 6092, 6093, 6094, 6095, 6096, 6097, 6098, 6099, 6100, 6101, 6102, 6103, 6104, 6105, 6106, 6107, 6108, 6109, 6110, 6111, 6112, 6113, 6114, 6115, 6116, 6117, 6118, 6119, 6120, 6121, 6122, 6123, 6124, 6125,
 6126, 6127, 6128, 6129, 6130, 6131, 6132, 6133, 6134, 6135, 6136, 6137, 6138, 6139, 6140, 6141, 6142, 6143, 6144, 6145, 6146, 6147, 6148, 6149, 6150, 6151, 6152, 6153, 6154, 6155, 6156, 6157, 6158, 6159, 6160,
 6161, 6162, 6163, 6164, 6165, 6166, 6167, 6168, 6169, 6170, 6171, 6172, 6173, 6174, 6175, 6176, 6177, 6178, 6179, 6180, 6181, 6182, 6183, 6184, 6185, 6186, 6187, 6188, 6189, 6190, 6191, 6192, 6193, 6194, 6195,
 6196, 6197, 6198, 6199, 6200, 6201, 6202, 6203, 6204, 6205, 6206, 6207, 6208, 6209, 6210, 6211, 6212, 6213, 6214, 6215, 6216, 6217, 6218, 6219, 6220, 6221, 6222, 6223, 6224, 6225, 6226, 6227, 6228, 6229, 6230,
 6231, 6232, 6233, 6234, 6235, 6236, 6237, 6238, 6239, 6240, 6241, 6242, 6243, 6244, 6245, 6246, 6247, 6248, 6249, 6250, 6251, 6252, 6253, 6254, 6255, 6256, 6257, 6258, 6259, 6260, 6261, 6262, 6263, 6264, 6265,
 6266, 6267, 6268, 6269, 6270, 6271, 6272, 6273, 6274, 6275, 6276, 6277, 6278, 6279, 6280, 6281, 6282, 6283, 6284, 6285, 6286, 6287, 6288, 6289, 6290, 6291, 6292, 6293, 6294, 6295, 6296, 6297, 6298, 6299, 6300,
 6301, 6302, 6303, 6304, 6305, 6306, 6307, 6308, 6309, 6310, 6311, 6312, 6313, 6314, 6315, 6316, 6317, 6318, 6319, 6320, 6321, 6322, 6323, 6324, 6325, 6326, 6327, 6328, 6329, 6330, 6331, 6332, 6333, 6334, 6335,
 6336, 6337, 6338, 6339, 6340, 6341, 6342, 6343, 6344, 6345, 6346, 6347, 6348, 6349, 6350, 6351, 6352, 6353, 6354, 6355, 6356, 6357, 6358, 6359, 6360, 6361, 6362, 6363, 6364, 6365, 6366, 6367, 6368, 6369, 6370,
 6371, 6372, 6373, 6374, 6375, 6376, 6377, 6378, 6379, 6380, 6381, 6382, 6383, 6384, 6385, 6386, 6387, 6388, 6389, 6390, 6391, 6392, 6393, 6394, 6395, 6396, 6397, 6398, 6399, 6400, 6401, 6402, 6403, 6404, 6405,
 6406, 6407, 6408, 6409, 6410, 6411, 6412, 6413, 6414, 6415, 6416, 6417, 6418, 6419, 6420, 6421, 6422, 6423, 6424, 6425, 6426, 6427, 6428, 6429, 6430, 6431, 6432, 6433, 6434, 6435, 6436, 6437, 6438, 6439, 6440,
 6441, 6442, 6443, 6444, 6445, 6446, 6447, 6448, 6449, 6450, 6451, 6452, 6453, 6454, 6455, 6456, 6457, 6458, 6459, 6460, 6461, 6462, 6463, 6464, 6465, 6466, 6467, 6468, 6469, 6470, 6471, 6472, 6473, 6474, 6475,
 6476, 6477, 6478, 6479, 6480, 6481, 6482, 6483, 6484, 6485, 6486, 6487, 6488, 6489, 6490, 6491, 6492, 6493, 6494, 6495, 6496, 6497, 6498, 6499, 6500, 6501, 6502, 6503, 6504, 6505, 6506, 6507, 6508, 6509, 6510,
 6511, 6512, 6513, 6514, 6515, 6516, 6517, 6518, 6519, 6520, 6521, 6522, 6523, 6524, 6525, 6526, 6527, 6528, 6529, 6530, 6531, 6532, 6533, 6534, 6535, 6536, 6537, 6538, 6539, 6540, 6541, 6542, 6543, 6544, 6545,
 6546, 6547, 6548, 6549, 6550, 6551, 6552, 6553, 6554, 6555, 6556, 6557, 6558, 6559, 6560, 6561, 6562, 6563, 6564, 6565, 6566, 6567, 6568, 6569, 6570, 6571, 6572, 6573, 6574, 6575, 6576, 6577, 6578, 6579, 6580,
 6581, 6582, 6583, 6584, 6585, 6586, 6587, 6588, 6589, 6590, 6591, 6592, 6593, 6594, 6595, 6596, 6597, 6598, 6599, 6600, 6601, 6602, 6603, 6604, 6605, 6606, 6607, 6608, 6609, 6610, 6611, 6612, 6613, 6614, 6615,
 6616, 6617, 6618, 6619, 6620, 6621, 6622, 6623, 6624, 6625, 6626, 6627, 6628, 6629, 6630, 6631, 6632, 6633, 6634, 6635, 6636, 6637, 6638, 6639, 6640, 6641, 6642, 6643, 6644, 6645, 6646, 6647, 6648, 6649, 6650,
 6651, 6652, 6653, 6654, 6655, 6656, 6657, 6658, 6659, 6660, 6661, 6662, 6663, 6664, 6665, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6670, 6671, 6672, 6673, 6674, 6675, 6676, 6677, 6678, 6679, 6680, 6681, 6682, 6683, 6684, 6685,
 6686, 6687, 6688, 6689, 6690, 6691, 6692, 6693, 6694, 6695, 6696, 6697, 6698, 6699, 6700, 6701, 6702, 6703, 6704, 6705, 6706, 6707, 6708, 6709, 6710, 6711, 6712, 6713, 6714, 6715, 6716, 6717, 6718, 6719, 6720,
 6721, 6722, 6723, 6724, 6725, 6726, 6727, 6728, 6729, 6730, 6731, 6732, 6733, 6734, 6735, 6736, 6737, 6738, 6739, 6740, 6741, 6742, 6743, 6744, 6745, 6746, 6747, 6748, 6749, 6750, 6751, 6752, 6753, 6754, 6755,
 6756, 6757, 6758, 6759, 6760, 6761, 6762, 6763, 6764, 6765, 6766, 6767, 6768, 6769, 6770, 6771, 6772, 6773, 6774, 6775, 6776, 6777, 6778, 6779, 6780, 6781, 6782, 6783, 6784, 6785, 6786, 6787, 6788, 6789, 6790,
 6791, 6792, 6793, 6794, 6795, 6796, 6797, 6798, 6799, 6800, 6801, 6802, 6803, 6804, 6805, 6806, 6807, 6808, 6809, 6810, 6811, 6812, 6813, 6814, 6815, 6816, 6817, 6818, 6819, 6820, 6821, 6822, 6823, 6824, 6825,
 6826, 6827, 6828, 6829, 6830, 6831, 6832, 6833, 6834, 6835, 6836, 6837, 6838, 6839, 6840, 6841, 6842, 6843, 6844, 6845, 6846, 6847, 6848, 6849, 6850, 6851, 6852, 6853, 6854, 6855, 6856, 6857, 6858, 6859, 6860,
 6861, 6862, 6863, 6864, 6865, 6866, 6867, 6868, 6869, 6870, 6871, 6872, 6873, 6874, 6875, 6876, 6877, 6878, 6879, 6880, 6881, 6882, 6883, 6884, 6885, 6886, 6887, 6888, 6889, 6890, 6891, 6892, 6893, 6894, 6895,
 6896, 6897, 6898, 6899, 6900, 6901, 6902, 6903, 6904, 6905, 6906, 6907, 6908, 6909, 6910, 6911, 6912, 6913, 6914, 6915, 6916, 6917, 6918, 6919, 6920, 6921, 6922, 6923, 6924, 6925, 6926, 6927, 6928, 6929, 6930,
 6931, 6932, 6933, 6934, 6935, 6936, 6937, 6938, 6939, 6940, 6941, 6942, 6943, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6951, 6952, 6953, 6954, 6955, 6956, 6957, 6958, 6959, 6960, 6961, 6962, 6963, 6964, 6965,
 6966, 6967, 6968, 6969, 6970, 6971, 6972, 6973, 6974, 6975, 6976, 6977, 6978, 6979, 6980, 6981, 6982, 6983, 6984, 6985, 6986, 6987, 6988, 6989, 6990, 6991, 6992, 6993, 6994, 6995, 6996, 6997, 6998, 6999, 7000,
 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005, 7006, 7007, 7008, 7009, 7010, 7011, 7012, 7013, 7014, 7015, 7016, 7017, 7018, 7019, 7020, 7021, 7022, 7023, 7024, 7025, 7026, 7027, 7028, 7029, 7030, 7031, 7032, 7033, 7034, 7035,
 7036, 7037, 7038, 7039, 7040, 7041, 7042, 7043, 7044, 7045, 7046, 7047, 7048, 7049, 7050, 7051, 7052, 7053, 7054, 7055, 7056, 7057, 7058, 7059, 7060, 7061, 7062, 7063, 7064, 7065, 7066, 7067, 7068, 7069, 7070,
 7071, 7072, 7073, 7074, 7075, 7076, 7077, 7078, 7079, 7080, 7081, 7082, 7083, 7084, 7085, 7086, 7087, 7088, 7089, 7090, 7091, 7092, 7093, 7094, 7095, 7096, 7097, 7098, 7099, 7100, 7101, 7102, 7103, 7104, 7105,
 7106, 7107, 7108, 7109, 7110, 7111, 7112, 7113, 7114, 7115, 7116, 7117, 7118, 7119, 7120, 7121, 7122, 7123, 7124, 7125, 7126, 7127, 7128, 7129, 7130, 7131, 7132, 7133, 7134, 7135, 7136, 7137, 7138, 7139, 7140,7141, 7142, 7143, 7144, 7145, 7146, 7147, 7148, 7149, 7150, 7151, 7152, 7153, 7154, 7155, 7156, 7157, 7158, 7159, 7160, 7161, 7162, 7163, 7164, 7165, 7166, 7167, 7168, 7169, 7170, 7171, 7172, 7173, 7174, 7175,
 7176, 7177, 7178, 7179, 7180, 7181, 7182, 7183, 7184, 7185, 7186, 7187, 7188, 7189, 7190, 7191, 7192, 7193, 7194, 7195, 7196, 7197, 7198, 7199, 7200, 7201, 7202, 7203, 7204, 7205, 7206, 7207, 7208, 7209, 7210,
 7211, 7212, 7213, 7214, 7215, 7216, 7217, 7218, 7219, 7220, 7221, 7222, 7223, 7224, 7225, 7226, 7227, 7228, 7229, 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234, 7235, 7236, 7237, 7238, 7239, 7240, 7241, 7242, 7243, 7244, 7245,
 7246, 7247, 7248, 7249, 7250, 7251, 7252, 7253, 7254, 7255, 7256, 7257, 7258, 7259, 7260, 7261, 7262, 7263, 7264, 7265, 7266, 7267, 7268, 7269, 7270, 7271, 7272, 7273, 7274, 7275, 7276, 7277, 7278, 7279, 7280,
 7281, 7282, 7283, 7284, 7285, 7286, 7287, 7288, 7289, 7290, 7291, 7292, 7293, 7294, 7295, 7296, 7297, 7298, 7299, 7300, 7301, 7302, 7303, 7304, 7305, 7306, 7307, 7308, 7309, 7310, 7311, 7312, 7313, 7314, 7315,
 7316, 7317, 7318, 7319, 7320, 7321, 7322, 7323, 7324, 7325, 7326, 7327, 7328, 7329, 7330, 7331, 7332, 7333, 7334, 7335, 7336, 7337, 7338, 7339, 7340, 7341, 7342, 7343, 7344, 7345, 7346, 7347, 7348, 7349, 7350,
 7351, 7352, 7353, 7354, 7355, 7356, 7357, 7358, 7359, 7360, 7361, 7362, 7363, 7364, 7365, 7366, 7367, 7368, 7369, 7370, 7371, 7372, 7373, 7374, 7375, 7376, 7377, 7378, 7379, 7380, 7381, 7382, 7383, 7384, 7385,
 7386, 7387, 7388, 7389, 7390, 7391, 7392, 7393, 7394, 7395, 7396, 7397, 7398, 7399, 7400, 7401, 7402, 7403, 7404, 7405, 7406, 7407, 7408, 7409, 7410, 7411, 7412, 7413, 7414, 7415, 7416, 7417, 7418, 7419, 7420,
 7421, 7422, 7423, 7424, 7425, 7426, 7427, 7428, 7429, 7430, 7431, 7432, 7433, 7434, 7435, 7436, 7437, 7438, 7439, 7440, 7441, 7442, 7443, 7444, 7445, 7446, 7447, 7448, 7449, 7450, 7451, 7452, 7453, 7454, 7455,
 7456, 7457, 7458, 7459, 7460, 7461, 7462, 7463, 7464, 7465, 7466, 7467, 7468, 7469, 7470, 7471, 7472, 7473, 7474, 7475, 7476, 7477, 7478, 7479, 7480, 7481, 7482, 7483, 7484, 7485, 7486, 7487, 7488, 7489, 7490,
 7491, 7492, 7493, 7494, 7495, 7496, 7497, 7498, 7499, 7500, 7501, 7502, 7503, 7504, 7505, 7506, 7507, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7513, 7514, 7515, 7516, 7517, 7518, 7519, 7520, 7521, 7522, 7523, 7524, 7525,
 7526, 7527, 7528, 7529, 7530, 7531, 7532, 7533, 7534, 7535, 7536, 7537, 7538, 7539, 7540, 7541, 7542, 7543, 7544, 7545, 7546, 7547, 7548, 7549, 7550, 7551, 7552, 7553, 7554, 7555, 7556, 7557, 7558, 7559, 7560,
 7561, 7562, 7563, 7564, 7565, 7566, 7567, 7568, 7569, 7570, 7571, 7572, 7573, 7574, 7575, 7576, 7577, 7578, 7579, 7580, 7581, 7582, 7583, 7584, 7585, 7586, 7587, 7588, 7589, 7590, 7591, 7592, 7593, 7594, 7595,
 7596, 7597, 7598, 7599, 7600, 7601, 7602, 7603, 7604, 7605, 7606, 7607, 7608, 7609, 7610, 7611, 7612, 7613, 7614, 7615, 7616, 7617, 7618, 7619, 7620, 7621, 7622, 7623, 7624, 7625, 7626, 7627, 7628, 7629, 7630,
 7631, 7632, 7633, 7634, 7635, 7636, 7637, 7638, 7639, 7640, 7641, 7642, 7643, 7644, 7645, 7646, 7647, 7648, 7649, 7650, 7651, 7652, 7653, 7654, 7655, 7656, 7657, 7658, 7659, 7660, 7661, 7662, 7663, 7664, 7665,
 7666, 7667, 7668, 7669, 7670, 7671, 7672, 7673, 7674, 7675, 7676, 7677, 7678, 7679, 7680, 7681, 7682, 7683, 7684, 7685, 7686, 7687, 7688, 7689, 7690, 7691, 7692, 7693, 7694, 7695, 7696, 7697, 7698, 7699, 7700,
 7701, 7702, 7703, 7704, 7705, 7706, 7707, 7708, 7709, 7710, 7711, 7712, 7713, 7714, 7715, 7716, 7717, 7718, 7719, 7720, 7721, 7722, 7723, 7724, 7725, 7726, 7727, 7728, 7729, 7730, 7731, 7732, 7733, 7734, 7735,
 7736, 7737, 7738, 7739, 7740, 7741, 7742, 7743, 7744, 7745, 7746, 7747, 7748, 7749, 7750, 7751, 7752, 7753, 7754, 7755, 7756, 7757, 7758, 7759, 7760, 7761, 7762, 7763, 7764, 7765, 7766, 7767, 7768, 7769, 7770,
 7771, 7772, 7773, 7774, 7775, 7776, 7777, 7778, 7779, 7780, 7781, 7782, 7783, 7784, 7785, 7786, 7787, 7788, 7789, 7790, 7791, 7792, 7793, 7794, 7795, 7796, 7797, 7798, 7799, 7800, 7801, 7802, 7803, 7804, 7805,
 7806, 7807, 7808, 7809, 7810, 7811, 7812, 7813, 7814, 7815, 7816, 7817, 7818, 7819, 7820, 7821, 7822, 7823, 7824, 7825, 7826, 7827, 7828, 7829, 7830, 7831, 7832, 7833, 7834, 7835, 7836, 7837, 7838, 7839, 7840,
 7841, 7842, 7843, 7844, 7845, 7846, 7847, 7848, 7849, 7850, 7851, 7852, 7853, 7854, 7855, 7856, 7857, 7858, 7859, 7860, 7861, 7862, 7863, 7864, 7865, 7866, 7867, 7868, 7869, 7870, 7871, 7872, 7873, 7874, 7875,
 7876, 7877, 7878, 7879, 7880, 7881, 7882, 7883, 7884, 7885, 7886, 7887, 7888, 7889, 7890, 7891, 7892, 7893, 7894, 7895, 7896, 7897, 7898, 7899, 7900, 7901, 7902, 7903, 7904, 7905, 7906, 7907, 7908, 7909, 7910,
 7911, 7912, 7913, 7914, 7915, 7916, 7917, 7918, 7919, 7920, 7921, 7922, 7923, 7924, 7925, 7926, 7927, 7928, 7929, 7930, 7931, 7932, 7933, 7934, 7935, 7936, 7937, 7938, 7939, 7940, 7941, 7942, 7943, 7944, 7945,
 7946, 7947, 7948, 7949, 7950, 7951, 7952, 7953, 7954, 7955, 7956, 7957, 7958, 7959, 7960, 7961, 7962, 7963, 7964, 7965, 7966, 7967, 7968, 7969, 7970, 7971, 7972, 7973, 7974, 7975, 7976, 7977, 7978, 7979, 7980,
 7981, 7982, 7983, 7984, 7985, 7986, 7987, 7988, 7989, 7990, 7991, 7992, 7993, 7994, 7995, 7996, 7997, 7998, 7999, 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003, 8004, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 8009, 8010, 8011, 8012, 8013, 8014, 8015,
 8016, 8017, 8018, 8019, 8020, 8021, 8022, 8023, 8024, 8025, 8026, 8027, 8028, 8029, 8030, 8031, 8032, 8033, 8034, 8035, 8036, 8037, 8038, 8039, 8040, 8041, 8042, 8043, 8044, 8045, 8046, 8047, 8048, 8049, 8050,
 8051, 8052, 8053, 8054, 8055, 8056, 8057, 8058, 8059, 8060, 8061, 8062, 8063, 8064, 8065, 8066, 8067, 8068, 8069, 8070, 8071, 8072, 8073, 8074, 8075, 8076, 8077, 8078, 8079, 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083, 8084, 8085,
 8086, 8087, 8088, 8089, 8090, 8091, 8092, 8093, 8094, 8095, 8096, 8097, 8098, 8099, 8100, 8101, 8102, 8103, 8104, 8105, 8106, 8107, 8108, 8109, 8110, 8111, 8112, 8113, 8114, 8115, 8116, 8117, 8118, 8119, 8120,
 8121, 8122, 8123, 8124, 8125, 8126, 8127, 8128, 8129, 8130, 8131, 8132, 8133, 8134, 8135, 8136, 8137, 8138, 8139, 8140, 8141, 8142, 8143, 8144, 8145, 8146, 8147, 8148, 8149, 8150, 8151, 8152, 8153, 8154, 8155,
 8156, 8157, 8158, 8159, 8160, 8161, 8162, 8163, 8164, 8165, 8166, 8167, 8168, 8169, 8170, 8171, 8172, 8173, 8174, 8175, 8176, 8177, 8178, 8179, 8180, 8181, 8182, 8183, 8184, 8185, 8186, 8187, 8188, 8189, 8190,8191, 8192, 8193, 8194, 8195, 8196, 8197, 8198, 8199, 8200, 8201, 8202, 8203, 8204, 8205, 8206, 8207, 8208, 8209, 8210, 8211, 8212, 8213, 8214, 8215, 8216, 8217, 8218, 8219, 8220, 8221, 8222, 8223, 8224, 8225,
 8226, 8227, 8228, 8229, 8230, 8231, 8232, 8233, 8234, 8235, 8236, 8237, 8238, 8239, 8240, 8241, 8242, 8243, 8244, 8245, 8246, 8247, 8248, 8249, 8250, 8251, 8252, 8253, 8254, 8255, 8256, 8257, 8258, 8259, 8260,
 8261, 8262, 8263, 8264, 8265, 8266, 8267, 8268, 8269, 8270, 8271, 8272, 8273, 8274, 8275, 8276, 8277, 8278, 8279, 8280, 8281, 8282, 8283, 8284, 8285, 8286, 8287, 8288, 8289, 8290, 8291, 8292, 8293, 8294, 8295,
 8296, 8297, 8298, 8299, 8300, 8301, 8302, 8303, 8304, 8305, 8306, 8307, 8308, 8309, 8310, 8311, 8312, 8313, 8314, 8315, 8316, 8317, 8318, 8319, 8320, 8321, 8322, 8323, 8324, 8325, 8326, 8327, 8328, 8329, 8330,
 8331, 8332, 8333, 8334, 8335, 8336, 8337, 8338, 8339, 8340, 8341, 8342, 8343, 8344, 8345, 8346, 8347, 8348, 8349, 8350, 8351, 8352, 8353, 8354, 8355, 8356, 8357, 8358, 8359, 8360, 8361, 8362, 8363, 8364, 8365,
 8366, 8367, 8368, 8369, 8370, 8371, 8372, 8373, 8374, 8375, 8376, 8377, 8378, 8379, 8380, 8381, 8382, 8383, 8384, 8385, 8386, 8387, 8388, 8389, 8390, 8391, 8392, 8393, 8394, 8395, 8396, 8397, 8398, 8399, 8400,
 8401, 8402, 8403, 8404, 8405, 8406, 8407, 8408, 8409, 8410, 8411, 8412, 8413, 8414, 8415, 8416, 8417, 8418, 8419, 8420, 8421, 8422, 8423, 8424, 8425, 8426, 8427, 8428, 8429, 8430, 8431, 8432, 8433, 8434, 8435,
 8436, 8437, 8438, 8439, 8440, 8441, 8442, 8443, 8444, 8445, 8446, 8447, 8448, 8449, 8450, 8451, 8452, 8453, 8454, 8455, 8456, 8457, 8458, 8459, 8460, 8461, 8462, 8463, 8464, 8465, 8466, 8467, 8468, 8469, 8470,
 8471, 8472, 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8478, 8479, 8480, 8481, 8482, 8483, 8484, 8485, 8486, 8487, 8488, 8489, 8490, 8491, 8492, 8493, 8494, 8495, 8496, 8497, 8498, 8499, 8500, 8501, 8502, 8503, 8504, 8505,
 8506, 8507, 8508, 8509, 8510, 8511, 8512, 8513, 8514, 8515, 8516, 8517, 8518, 8519, 8520, 8521, 8522, 8523, 8524, 8525, 8526, 8527, 8528, 8529, 8530, 8531, 8532, 8533, 8534, 8535, 8536, 8537, 8538, 8539, 8540,
 8541, 8542, 8543, 8544, 8545, 8546, 8547, 8548, 8549, 8550, 8551, 8552, 8553, 8554, 8555, 8556, 8557, 8558, 8559, 8560, 8561, 8562, 8563, 8564, 8565, 8566, 8567, 8568, 8569, 8570, 8571, 8572, 8573, 8574, 8575,
 8576, 8577, 8578, 8579, 8580, 8581, 8582, 8583, 8584, 8585, 8586, 8587, 8588, 8589, 8590, 8591, 8592, 8593, 8594, 8595, 8596, 8597, 8598, 8599, 8600, 8601, 8602, 8603, 8604, 8605, 8606, 8607, 8608, 8609, 8610,
 8611, 8612, 8613, 8614, 8615, 8616, 8617, 8618, 8619, 8620, 8621, 8622, 8623, 8624, 8625, 8626, 8627, 8628, 8629, 8630, 8631, 8632, 8633, 8634, 8635, 8636, 8637, 8638, 8639, 8640, 8641, 8642, 8643, 8644, 8645,
 8646, 8647, 8648, 8649, 8650, 8651, 8652, 8653, 8654, 8655, 8656, 8657, 8658, 8659, 8660, 8661, 8662, 8663, 8664, 8665, 8666, 8667, 8668, 8669, 8670, 8671, 8672, 8673, 8674, 8675, 8676, 8677, 8678, 8679, 8680,
 8681, 8682, 8683, 8684, 8685, 8686, 8687, 8688, 8689, 8690, 8691, 8692, 8693, 8694, 8695, 8696, 8697, 8698, 8699, 8700, 8701, 8702, 8703, 8704, 8705, 8706, 8707, 8708, 8709, 8710, 8711, 8712, 8713, 8714, 8715,
 8716, 8717, 8718, 8719, 8720, 8721, 8722, 8723, 8724, 8725, 8726, 8727, 8728, 8729, 8730, 8731, 8732, 8733, 8734, 8735, 8736, 8737, 8738, 8739, 8740, 8741, 8742, 8743, 8744, 8745, 8746, 8747, 8748, 8749, 8750,
 8751, 8752, 8753, 8754, 8755, 8756, 8757, 8758, 8759, 8760, 8761, 8762, 8763, 8764, 8765, 8766, 8767, 8768, 8769, 8770, 8771, 8772, 8773, 8774, 8775, 8776, 8777, 8778, 8779, 8780, 8781, 8782, 8783, 8784, 8785,
 8786, 8787, 8788, 8789, 8790, 8791, 8792, 8793, 8794, 8795, 8796, 8797, 8798, 8799, 8800, 8801, 8802, 8803, 8804, 8805, 8806, 8807, 8808, 8809, 8810, 8811, 8812, 8813, 8814, 8815, 8816, 8817, 8818, 8819, 8820,
 8821, 8822, 8823, 8824, 8825, 8826, 8827, 8828, 8829, 8830, 8831, 8832, 8833, 8834, 8835, 8836, 8837, 8838, 8839, 8840, 8841, 8842, 8843, 8844, 8845, 8846, 8847, 8848, 8849, 8850, 8851, 8852, 8853, 8854, 8855,
 8856, 8857, 8858, 8859, 8860, 8861, 8862, 8863, 8864, 8865, 8866, 8867, 8868, 8869, 8870, 8871, 8872, 8873, 8874, 8875, 8876, 8877, 8878, 8879, 8880, 8881, 8882, 8883, 8884, 8885, 8886, 8887, 8888, 8889, 8890,
 8891, 8892, 8893, 8894, 8895, 8896, 8897, 8898, 8899, 8900, 8901, 8902, 8903, 8904, 8905, 8906, 8907, 8908, 8909, 8910, 8911, 8912, 8913, 8914, 8915, 8916, 8917, 8918, 8919, 8920, 8921, 8922, 8923, 8924, 8925,
 8926, 8927, 8928, 8929, 8930, 8931, 8932, 8933, 8934, 8935, 8936, 8937, 8938, 8939, 8940, 8941, 8942, 8943, 8944, 8945, 8946, 8947, 8948, 8949, 8950, 8951, 8952, 8953, 8954, 8955, 8956, 8957, 8958, 8959, 8960,
 8961, 8962, 8963, 8964, 8965, 8966, 8967, 8968, 8969, 8970, 8971, 8972, 8973, 8974, 8975, 8976, 8977, 8978, 8979, 8980, 8981, 8982, 8983, 8984, 8985, 8986, 8987, 8988, 8989, 8990, 8991, 8992, 8993, 8994, 8995,
 8996, 8997, 8998, 8999, 9000, 9001, 9002, 9003, 9004, 9005, 9006, 9007, 9008, 9009, 9010, 9011, 9012, 9013, 9014, 9015, 9016, 9017, 9018, 9019, 9020, 9021, 9022, 9023, 9024, 9025, 9026, 9027, 9028, 9029, 9030,
 9031, 9032, 9033, 9034, 9035, 9036, 9037, 9038, 9039, 9040, 9041, 9042, 9043, 9044, 9045, 9046, 9047, 9048, 9049, 9050, 9051, 9052, 9053, 9054, 9055, 9056, 9057, 9058, 9059, 9060, 9061, 9062, 9063, 9064, 9065,
 9066, 9067, 9068, 9069, 9070, 9071, 9072, 9073, 9074, 9075, 9076, 9077, 9078, 9079, 9080, 9081, 9082, 9083, 9084, 9085, 9086, 9087, 9088, 9089, 9090, 9091, 9092, 9093, 9094, 9095, 9096, 9097, 9098, 9099, 9100,
 9101, 9102, 9103, 9104, 9105, 9106, 9107, 9108, 9109, 9110, 9111, 9112, 9113, 9114, 9115, 9116, 9117, 9118, 9119, 9120, 9121, 9122, 9123, 9124, 9125, 9126, 9127, 9128, 9129, 9130, 9131, 9132, 9133, 9134, 9135,
 9136, 9137, 9138, 9139, 9140, 9141, 9142, 9143, 9144, 9145, 9146, 9147, 9148, 9149, 9150, 9151, 9152, 9153, 9154, 9155, 9156, 9157, 9158, 9159, 9160, 9161, 9162, 9163, 9164, 9165, 9166, 9167, 9168, 9169, 9170,
 9171, 9172, 9173, 9174, 9175, 9176, 9177, 9178, 9179, 9180, 9181, 9182, 9183, 9184, 9185, 9186, 9187, 9188, 9189, 9190, 9191, 9192, 9193, 9194, 9195, 9196, 9197, 9198, 9199, 9200, 9201, 9202, 9203, 9204, 9205,
 9206, 9207, 9208, 9209, 9210, 9211, 9212, 9213, 9214, 9215, 9216, 9217, 9218, 9219, 9220, 9221, 9222, 9223, 9224, 9225, 9226, 9227, 9228, 9229, 9230, 9231, 9232, 9233, 9234, 9235, 9236, 9237, 9238, 9239, 9240,9241, 9242, 9243, 9244, 9245, 9246, 9247, 9248, 9249, 9250, 9251, 9252, 9253, 9254, 9255, 9256, 9257, 9258, 9259, 9260, 9261, 9262, 9263, 9264, 9265, 9266, 9267, 9268, 9269, 9270, 9271, 9272, 9273, 9274, 9275,
 9276, 9277, 9278, 9279, 9280, 9281, 9282, 9283, 9284, 9285, 9286, 9287, 9288, 9289, 9290, 9291, 9292, 9293, 9294, 9295, 9296, 9297, 9298, 9299, 9300, 9301, 9302, 9303, 9304, 9305, 9306, 9307, 9308, 9309, 9310,
 9311, 9312, 9313, 9314, 9315, 9316, 9317, 9318, 9319, 9320, 9321, 9322, 9323, 9324, 9325, 9326, 9327, 9328, 9329, 9330, 9331, 9332, 9333, 9334, 9335, 9336, 9337, 9338, 9339, 9340, 9341, 9342, 9343, 9344, 9345,
 9346, 9347, 9348, 9349, 9350, 9351, 9352, 9353, 9354, 9355, 9356, 9357, 9358, 9359, 9360, 9361, 9362, 9363, 9364, 9365, 9366, 9367, 9368, 9369, 9370, 9371, 9372, 9373, 9374, 9375, 9376, 9377, 9378, 9379, 9380,
 9381, 9382, 9383, 9384, 9385, 9386, 9387, 9388, 9389, 9390, 9391, 9392, 9393, 9394, 9395, 9396, 9397, 9398, 9399, 9400, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9404, 9405, 9406, 9407, 9408, 9409, 9410, 9411, 9412, 9413, 9414, 9415,
 9416, 9417, 9418, 9419, 9420, 9421, 9422, 9423, 9424, 9425, 9426, 9427, 9428, 9429, 9430, 9431, 9432, 9433, 9434, 9435, 9436, 9437, 9438, 9439, 9440, 9441, 9442, 9443, 9444, 9445, 9446, 9447, 9448, 9449, 9450,
 9451, 9452, 9453, 9454, 9455, 9456, 9457, 9458, 9459, 9460, 9461, 9462, 9463, 9464, 9465, 9466, 9467, 9468, 9469, 9470, 9471, 9472, 9473, 9474, 9475, 9476, 9477, 9478, 9479, 9480, 9481, 9482, 9483, 9484, 9485,
 9486, 9487, 9488, 9489, 9490, 9491, 9492, 9493, 9494, 9495, 9496, 9497, 9498, 9499, 9500, 9501, 9502, 9503, 9504, 9505, 9506, 9507, 9508, 9509, 9510, 9511, 9512, 9513, 9514, 9515, 9516, 9517, 9518, 9519, 9520,
 9521, 9522, 9523, 9524, 9525, 9526, 9527, 9528, 9529, 9530, 9531, 9532, 9533, 9534, 9535, 9536, 9537, 9538, 9539, 9540, 9541, 9542, 9543, 9544, 9545, 9546, 9547, 9548, 9549, 9550, 9551, 9552, 9553, 9554, 9555,
 9556, 9557, 9558, 9559, 9560, 9561, 9562, 9563, 9564, 9565, 9566, 9567, 9568, 9569, 9570, 9571, 9572, 9573, 9574, 9575, 9576, 9577, 9578, 9579, 9580, 9581, 9582, 9583, 9584, 9585, 9586, 9587, 9588, 9589, 9590,
 9591, 9592, 9593, 9594, 9595, 9596, 9597, 9598, 9599, 9600, 9601, 9602, 9603, 9604, 9605, 9606, 9607, 9608, 9609, 9610, 9611, 9612, 9613, 9614, 9615, 9616, 9617, 9618, 9619, 9620, 9621, 9622, 9623, 9624, 9625,
 9626, 9627, 9628, 9629, 9630, 9631, 9632, 9633, 9634, 9635, 9636, 9637, 9638, 9639, 9640, 9641, 9642, 9643, 9644, 9645, 9646, 9647, 9648, 9649, 9650, 9651, 9652, 9653, 9654, 9655, 9656, 9657, 9658, 9659, 9660,
 9661, 9662, 9663, 9664, 9665, 9666, 9667, 9668, 9669, 9670, 9671, 9672, 9673, 9674, 9675, 9676, 9677, 9678, 9679, 9680, 9681, 9682, 9683, 9684, 9685, 9686, 9687, 9688, 9689, 9690, 9691, 9692, 9693, 9694, 9695,
 9696, 9697, 9698, 9699, 9700, 9701, 9702, 9703, 9704, 9705, 9706, 9707, 9708, 9709, 9710, 9711, 9712, 9713, 9714, 9715, 9716, 9717, 9718, 9719, 9720, 9721, 9722, 9723, 9724, 9725, 9726, 9727, 9728, 9729, 9730,
 9731, 9732, 9733, 9734, 9735, 9736, 9737, 9738, 9739, 9740, 9741, 9742, 9743, 9744, 9745, 9746, 9747, 9748, 9749, 9750, 9751, 9752, 9753, 9754, 9755, 9756, 9757, 9758, 9759, 9760, 9761, 9762, 9763, 9764, 9765,
 9766, 9767, 9768, 9769, 9770, 9771, 9772, 9773, 9774, 9775, 9776, 9777, 9778, 9779, 9780, 9781, 9782, 9783, 9784, 9785, 9786, 9787, 9788, 9789, 9790, 9791, 9792, 9793, 9794, 9795, 9796, 9797, 9798, 9799, 9800,
 9801, 9802, 9803, 9804, 9805, 9806, 9807, 9808, 9809, 9810, 9811, 9812, 9813, 9814, 9815, 9816, 9817, 9818, 9819, 9820, 9821, 9822, 9823, 9824, 9825, 9826, 9827, 9828, 9829, 9830, 9831, 9832, 9833, 9834, 9835,
 9836, 9837, 9838, 9839, 9840, 9841, 9842, 9843, 9844, 9845, 9846, 9847, 9848, 9849, 9850, 9851, 9852, 9853, 9854, 9855, 9856, 9857, 9858, 9859, 9860, 9861, 9862, 9863, 9864, 9865, 9866, 9867, 9868, 9869, 9870,
 9871, 9872, 9873, 9874, 9875, 9876, 9877, 9878, 9879, 9880, 9881, 9882, 9883, 9884, 9885, 9886, 9887, 9888, 9890, 9891, 9892, 9893, 9894, 9895`

Answer (score 2):

> What is causing this?

Loading a product collection with hundreds of products. I can only guess, but if you do not show all these products on one page, it's caused by a badly written theme or extension.

Inspect the stack trace when this occurs to find out more.

Comment: +1 for this answer, aoe_profiler + mytop work well. Links to both here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both/13992#13992