# Magento 2: What is the best way to do caching?

Tags: magento2, cache

I'm newbie to Magento 2.

What is the best way to do caching?

Should we use external 3rd party service for it or use default one.

I have more than 1 million SKU's.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-full-page-cache-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento SE!

While not directly answering your question, I have a similar write up on some tuning/caching options for Magento 1.x, while not all applies but some tools still relevant:

- [Full Page Cache on CE 1.8 - An FPC Magento Module? Varnish? Both?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both/13992#13992)

To summarize:

> The best approach is to start at the lower points of the stack and
>   optimize up to the frontend of Magento.

At this point when fully exhausted optimizing the server stack, code and services then look to caching. The Varnish implementation in Magento 2.x by default along with Redis as a cache/session storage should handle 50k.

A few links around performance to help.

- https://github.com/lubana89/magento2-PagePerformanceStatistics based off performance-bookmarklet
- https://gist.github.com/IvanChepurnyi/776d56770eecd5d3e39bde6ea41f9dca Optimize autoloader
- https://github.com/sysown/proxysql High-performance MySQL proxy
- https://github.com/bvanhoekelen/performance PHP performance tool analyzer
- https://github.com/innotop/innotop top like for MySQL/InnoDB
- https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl MySQL tuning
- https://github.com/rapidloop/rtop remote monitoring tool via SSH
- https://github.com/stefanjudis/is-http2-cli CLI Module to check for http/2 support
- https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_ServerPush allow for HTTP/2 Server Push
- https://github.com/sitespeedio/sitespeed.io analyze and optimize your website speed and performance
- https://github.com/fballiano/magento2-defer-javascripts Defer Javascripts module
- https://github.com/gamenet/redis-memory-analyzer Redis memory profiler to find the RAM bottlenecks
- https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools Performance analysis tools
- https://github.com/magepal/magento2-catalog-lazy-load Catalog pages: loading your images on demand